# How to do Named Entity Tagging in python for Stanford coreNLP?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, tagging, named-entity-recognition

I'm new at NLP. And was trying my hand at Stanford Named Entity Recognition. Right now, I used the Stanford NLP to generate xml file of the text files. Now I want to generate text files from the xml files such that the named entities are replaced by the tag in this now? How should I do that? Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do or how you want to do it.
If you want to do your processing in Python, I'd advise for you to check out: https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python